# RSQL and Spring HATEOS integration

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc

I have RSQL integration in my spring Bootproject already.
https://github.com/jirutka/rsql-parser

We did not have Spring HATEOS all this while, so RSQL was used to filter data like this

`http://localhost:8800/<appname>/sports/?q=name==NFL*`
After introducing @RestRepositoryResource the response is completely changed and I am not able to use the RSQL. 
http://localhost:8800//sports/244 - works, which is the NFL resource.
But I dont want to right methods with @param in the repository level and want to have RSQL integrated for this.

Any one have some idea?

I can give more examples if needed.